# MySQL Workbench: splitting strings function

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

I've been trying to split the 'orders' string into a new table row, that follows its corresponding 'order_id'

The table name that the original columns feature in are called 'customer_order'

From This;

```
  order_id| orders   
      2837| motor, wheel, seat, battery, belt, glass    
      2394| belt
      9283| glass, seat, motor
```

To this;

```
   order_id| split_orders   
       2837| motor    
       2837| wheel   
       2837| seat    
       2837| battery
       2837| belt    
       2837| glass
       2394| belt
       9283| glass
       9283| seat
       9283| motor
```

I'm using SQL Workbench, and I've tried a handful of different ways from scouring the internet for the past 2 days such as;

```
select order_id, Value 
from customer_order
cross apply STRING_SPLIT (orders, ',');
```

I'm new to SQL and writing code, I get that I'm bad at it. I've been tearing my hair out trying to figure it out but I just can't seem to get it right, I always end up with a syntax error

Doesn't anyone know why I can't get it to work? I get that I'm doing something wrong but I keep trying and failing at working out where I'm messing up

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query

```
SELECT
  order_id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(orders, ', ', n.digit+1), ', ', -1) color
FROM
  customer_order
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT 0 digit UNION ALL 
   SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
   SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
   SELECT 3 UNION ALL 
   SELECT 4 UNION ALL 
   SELECT 5) n
  ON LENGTH(REPLACE(orders, ',' , '')) <= LENGTH(orders)-n.digit
ORDER BY
  order_id,
  n.digit
```

[***Check Demo Here***](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8be7bd6fc46f571a2663777fd140cb08).

This will work only upto 5 orders separated by comma. You have to increase the number of `UNION ALL` if you have more than 5 strings in your list.